# Magento Enterprise - Product Search use a specific scope view

Tags: magento-enterprise, php, mysql, catalogsearch

I have a question. I have a Magento Enterprise and have two store views. Each store view has slight different products. What I want is when I am in a store view lets say one of them is called USA and I do a product search I need the search box to realize I am in the "USA" store view and only search for the products that are setup within that store view.

My question is what mysql table would the relationship be stored that connects a product to a specific store view? Or how would I alter the query to take into account what store view the end user is currently viewing?

Answer (score 2):

Change the visibility attribute in your product and then the search results will only show the visible products you have for that storeview.

[image]

Comment: I have my products setup by going to the Manage Products page. I then change the scope view to a specific store view (lets say the "Singapore store" view). I then click add a product and add all the product details and of course assign it to a "Singapore store" specific category for that store view.
 However the product is still visible in the search box if I am on the customer facing side of the site and change the store view to say USA store.